# ProvisionException: Unable to provision, in play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am getting these error 
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in models.factory.FactoryHandler. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at models.factory.FactoryHandler.class(FactoryHandler.scala:7)
  while locating models.factory.FactoryHandler
    for parameter 0 at controllers.DirectUserController.<init>(DirectUserController.scala:90)
  while locating controllers.DirectUserController
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:124)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
     play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:111)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.routes(Application.scala:240)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:90)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
```

here is the code

```
class FactoryHandler(var s:String="real") {
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  log.debug("choice {}",s)
}
```

and this is line no 90 at DirectUserController

```
    class DirectUserController @Inject() (var factory:FactoryHandler) extends Controller {
//other Action code 
}
```

I have also added code in routes file

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

i am using play framework 2.4 please help me why i am getting this error

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a @Inject() in FactoryHandler code.. read the error, I think it says what's wrong with it.

Comment: class FactoryHandler @inject()(var s:String="real") when i do this i get compile time error injection not found: type inject

Comment: Capital "i" and import it, I guess